# Laravel middleware is "bypassed" when i submit the invalid token, but when it is a valid token, the middleware is executed

Tags: laravel-5, jwt, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

all my fellow friends, i have a question.

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['ensure.role:store', 'auth:api']
]
```

For simplification,

```
i have two roles : ADMIN and STORE
```

I have created a middleware that will validate user role, and if the user role is correct, then will allow the user to access the route.

It works fine.
I tried using ADMIN Jwt Token to access STORE routes, and rightfully i am kicked out, and vice versa.

But now, if i modify the token, lets say i add a string to any part of the token, and try to access any route, actually i am allowed to.

I tried var_dump and print something on the related middleware, and here are my observation.

```
1. If the token is VALID as one of the user role, then 
the var_dump is executed, (means the middleware is executed)
2. if the token is INVALID as in i add / modify the original
token, then the var_dump is not executed, and so are the 
others route middleware.
```

I am wondering what causes this behavior, and what could be the fix for this issue, as i need to throw 401 unauthenticated in any token invalid case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
After series of testing and reading, i found out that after laravel 5.3 and above, constructor is called before middleware. And because in my constructor i am using an user object before i am authenticated by the middleware, i encountered constructor error, because user is null.

Of course it is a bad practice to use user object in the construct, however due to the convenience of usage, i still decided to use it.

It sounds complex to use closure based middleware as alternative solution

So i use a workaround to do it.

I create a helper function that return me true if there is an user object or return abort(401); if there is no user object, then add this one line to all the constructors.

```
$this->checkAccess = EnsureRoleUtil::check('admin');
```

After that, i just do my next constructor as normally

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->checkAccess = EnsureRoleUtil::check('admin');

    $this->user = Auth::user();
    $this->categoryM = new CategoryManager($this->user);
}
```

However, to be noted, it is not a good practice, it is just a hack / workaround.